# Escaping quotes automatically

Tags: java, string

I have a text file that looks something like:

```
word("word1");
word("word2");
word("word3");
etc
```

(copied from a website)

I want to write a java program to get each word (word1, word2 etc) and put it in a String[].
The output would be

```
my_list = {"word1", "word2" etc};
```

I wanted put the raw input between brackets to make it a string and then process it, but the problem is I would need to manually escape each of the "" in the file.

How can I workaround this?

Comment: why don't you use regular expressions?

Comment: Does each line have exactly `word("` and then a text and then `");`?

Comment: Write a Java program that implements the method `word(String str)`.  Embed your list as the body of another method.  Run that method, have the `word` method write out your words however you want them.

Comment: @MCEmperor yes word() is not a function, it is just a syntax

Comment: @Paolof76 I don't know about regular expressions

Comment: @HotLicks word is not a method, it is just a syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
try {
        String text = "word(\"word1\");\n"
                + "word(\"word2\");\n"
                + "word(\"word3\");\n"
                + "etc";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\".*?\"");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            list.add(matcher.group(0));
        }
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder("my_list = {");
        for (Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                out.append(iterator.next());
            if(iterator.hasNext())
                out.append(", ");
        }
        out.append("};");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, out.toString());
    } catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
        // Syntax error in the regular expression
    }
```

Comment: I can't append manually the "\" before each each quote (there are too many of them)

Comment: @giulio If you read the text from a file or gui you don't need to escape the quote

Answer (score 1):

Why are you even doing word()? If you don't need to, remove it and just have the text file look like this:

```
word1
word2
word3
```

If you actually need the text file to look like this, have each line read by being split with:

```
String thisWord = parsed.split("\"")[1];
```